# Tychonoff spaces with small weight

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Is there a Tychonoff space $(X,\tau)$ such that $|X| = 2^\kappa$ and $(X,\tau)$ has weight $\kappa$ (= a basis consisting of $\kappa$ elements)?

Comment: What about $2^\kappa$, as the generalized Cantor cube?

Comment: Oh - excellent, thanks! I was looking too far. Please post as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space $\{0,1\}^\kappa$ has weight $\kappa$ and the required cardinality. For a connected example, that contains all Tychonoff spaces of weight $\kappa$ as a subspace, consider the Tychonoff cubes $[0,1]^\kappa$ which have cardinality $(2^{\aleph_0})^\kappa = 2^\kappa$ as well.